# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BaseRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in the RegisterModule

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I cannot understand why I'm getting this error, while the code seems correct t me.

I have my `BaseRepository<T= any>` in nest.js application where I can pass only the document.

I'm trying to build a module that implements register by email logic.

The error states in the title of the question.

Here is my code, please help me, I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

`register.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Creator, CreatorDocument, CreatorSchema } from '../data/models/Creator'
import { BaseRepository } from "../repositories/BaseRepository";
import { RegisterController } from "../controllers/register.controller";
import { RegisterService } from "../services/register.service";
import { RegisterMapper } from '../mappers/register.mapper'

@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Creator.name, schema: CreatorSchema }]),
    ],
    controllers: [RegisterController],
    providers: [
      BaseRepository,
      RegisterMapper,
        {
            provide: RegisterService,
            useFactory: async (
                repository: BaseRepository,
                mapper: RegisterMapper
            ) => {
                return new RegisterService(repository, mapper)
            },
            inject: [BaseRepository, RegisterMapper]
        }
    ],
    exports: []
})

export class RegisterModule {}
```

`register.controller.ts`

```
import { Body, Controller, HttpStatus, Post } from '@nestjs/common'
import {RegisterService} from "../services/register.service";
import {RegisterDto} from "../types/dtos/register.dto";


@Controller()
export class RegisterController {
    constructor(
        private service: RegisterService
    ) { }

    @Post('/api/register')
    async register(@Body() registerDTO: RegisterDto) {
      await this.service.createAccount(registerDTO)
      return HttpStatus.OK
    }
}
```

`register.service.ts`

```
import {BaseRepository} from "../repositories/BaseRepository";
import { Creator, CreatorDocument } from '../data/models/Creator'
import {RegisterDto} from "../types/dtos/register.dto";
import {Injectable} from "@nestjs/common";
import { RegisterMapper } from '../mappers/register.mapper'
import { errors } from '../errors'
import { mailer } from '../utils/nodemailer'

@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {
    constructor(
      private readonly repository: BaseRepository<Creator>,
      private readonly mapper: RegisterMapper
    ) { }

    async createAccount (doc: RegisterDto) {
      const emailExist = await this.existByEmail(doc.email)
      if (emailExist) {
        return errors.EMAIL_EXIST()
      }
      const created = await this.repository.create(this.mapper.toDomain(doc))
      await mailer(doc.email)
      return created
    }

    private async existByEmail(email: string): Promise<boolean> {
      console.log(email)
      console.log(this.repository)
      const response = await this.repository.get({email}, {})
      return !!response.email;
    }
}
```

`register.mapper.ts`

```
import { Mapper } from '../types/interfaces/mapper'
import { Creator } from '../data/models/Creator'
import { RegisterDto } from '../types/dtos/register.dto'
import { UserRole } from '../types/enums/UserRole'
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class RegisterMapper implements Mapper<Creator> {
    toDomain(dto: RegisterDto): Creator {
        const creator = new Creator()
        creator.name = dto.name
        creator.email = dto.email
        creator.password = dto.password
        creator.asset = dto.asset
        creator.description = dto.description
        creator.isVerified = false
        creator.type = UserRole.CREATOR
        creator.links = dto.links
        creator.notifications = dto.notifications

        return creator
    }

    toDTO(domain: Creator): RegisterDto {
        return undefined;
    }

}
```

`base.repository.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ModelType } from '@typegoose/typegoose/lib/types'
import { DuplicateKeyError } from "../errors/DuplicateKeyError"
import { DocumentNotFoundError } from "../errors/DocumentNotFoundError"

@Injectable()
export class BaseRepository<T = any> {
    constructor(
        private Model: any
    ) {
    }

    async create (object): Promise<T> {
        const Model = this.Model

        const uniqueKey = Model.getUniqueKey ? Model.getUniqueKey() : null
        if (uniqueKey && object[uniqueKey]) {
            const criteria = {
                [uniqueKey]: object[uniqueKey]
            }
            const existing = await Model.findOne(criteria)
            if (existing) {
                throw new DuplicateKeyError(Model, criteria)
            }
        }

        const model = new Model(object)
        return model.save()
    }

    async update (criteria, object, options = {}) {
        const Model = this.Model

        const uniqueKey = Model.getUniqueKey ? Model.getUniqueKey() : '_id'

        const data = { ...object }
        delete data[uniqueKey]
        delete data.createdAt

        return this.updateRaw(criteria, { $set: { ...data } }, options)
    }

    async updateRaw (criteria, data, options = {}) {
        const query = this._getDbQuery(criteria, options)
        const result = await this.Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, data, { new: true, ...options })

        if (!result) {
            throw new DocumentNotFoundError(this.Model, query)
        }

        return result
    }

    async save (modelInstance) {
        return modelInstance.save()
    }

    async get (criteria, options: any = {}): Promise<T | undefined> {
        console.log(this._getDbQuery(criteria, options))
        const promise = this.Model.findOne(this._getDbQuery(criteria, options))

        if (options.select) {
            promise.select(options.select)
        }

        return promise
    }

    async find (criteria, options): Promise<ReturnType<ModelType<T>['find']>> {
        return this.Model.find(this._getDbQuery(criteria, options))
    }

    async resolve (criteria): Promise<T> {
        return this.Model.resolve(this._getDbQuery(criteria))
    }

    async count (query) {
        return this.Model.countDocuments(this._getDbQuery(query))
    }

    async delete (criteria) {
        return this.Model.remove(this._getDbQuery(criteria))
    }

    _getDbQuery (criteria, options: any = {}) {
        if ('getDbQuery' in criteria) {
            const dbQuery = criteria.getDbQuery(options)
            return 'find' in dbQuery
                ? dbQuery.find
                : dbQuery
        } else {
            return criteria
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: as you're annotated `BaseRepository` with `@Injectable()`, NestJS tries to resolve that `Model` field but it can't since its type is `any` and you haven't used `@Inject()`. That's why you're getting that error.

Comment: @MicaelLevi i used inject now, but it still has an error

Comment: did you provide the value to inject as well? read the docs https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#custom-providers

Comment: @MicaelLevi now passed, seems work, but at the same time I got another error, it says that my `cannot findOne of undefined`, because when I'm doing `BaseRepository<Creator>` it should pass `Creator` model but it shows me that `Model { undefined }` in `console.log`, so, maybe u know how to solve it too? T_T

`register.service.ts` file above in the question. it won't pass my model there in the `BaseRepository`

Can u please make an answer, to mark it

Comment: Generics (the values inside the `<>`) are _type_ information, not values, so it's not available at runtime. You'd need to still pass the `Creator` object to your `BaseRepository` so that it knows _which_ model it's working with

Comment: @JayMcDoniel but still, I do not understand how to use it! It should be represented in such type of architecture

Comment: You should probably make an abstract class that models what should happen, then child classes that extend it and pass up the proper model so that you have all these methods available, then each child class can be injected into a service and worked with correctly

Comment: @JayMcDoniel
Since I don't want to make child classes, and just implement 1 class with a generic type of model, ur advice does not suitable for me, but u gave me another idea which I'm going to try, thanks!

Comment: @DaniilSinelnik if you don't want to make child classes, you need to instantiate concrete repository via `useFactory` and register it in module `providers`, then inject into `RegisterService` with `@Inject('key_registered_in_providers')`